# Correlation of forecast target and forecast error in time-series framework

Tags: time-series, forecasting, covariance, error

**Setup:** In a time-series context, let $y_t$ denote a target variable that is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable, and let $h_t$ denote a forecast of $y_t$ that is $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ measurable. That is, the forecast is constructed using time $t-1$ information. Let:
\begin{equation}
u_t = h_t - y_t
\end{equation}
denote the forecast error.

**Question:** Under what conditions might we expect $\textrm{cov}(u_t, y_t) = 0$?

More generally, is this a standard assumption to make? And if so, how is it usually justified?

**A (hand-wavey) answer:** If the forecast error is correlated with the forecast target, this suggests there is useful information that our forecast is not capturing which is instead being captured in the forecast error. So for a badly-constructed forecast, we might expect the covariance term to be non-zero while for a well-constructed forecast we might expect it to be zero. This answer is obviously unsatisfactory since it is very vague (and non-mathematical) around what badly-constructed and well-constructed really mean.

**AR(1) Counterexample:** Extending @jbowman comment below, let $y_t = \beta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$, and let $h_t = \beta y_{t-1}$, which is the optimal forecast. Then $u_t = -\epsilon_t$, and $\textrm{cov}(u_t, y_t) = \textrm{cov}(-\epsilon_t, \beta y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) = -\textrm{Var}(\epsilon_t)$ assuming that $\textrm{cov}(y_{t-1}, \epsilon_t) = 0$. So in general there appears to be no reason to expect the covariance term to be zero.

Comment: Try this model:  $y_t = 0 + u_t$.  My forecast equals $0$ at all times, and this is, in fact, the optimal forecast. Therefore, $u_t$ is the forecast error.  Is $y_t$ correlated with $u_t$?  Why?  Would this correlation go away if I replaced the $0$ with something else?

Comment: @jbowman If I understand correctly, you're pointing out that in your example $y_t$ and $u_t$ are perfectly correlated. On the other hand, if $h_t = y_{t-1}$ in your example, and the residual term in $y_t = 0 + u_t$ is *iid*, then the covariance term will be equal to zero (albeit obviously the forecast is sub-optimal). So is the conclusion to draw from this that we would not necessarily expect $cov(u_t,y_t)=0$, and that it would be a non-standard assumption to make? If I've understood correctly, I'd be happy for you to put this as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that later on, something expanded of course.  Thanks!